# Magento2 filter products based on location (custom attribute) programmatically

Tags: magento2, attributes, collection, product-collection, magento2.4

I have a Magento2 Store (v2.4) where I have multiple locations. for (eg. Jaipur, Delhi, Mumbai etc). I have managed locations using custom attribute using multiple dropdown list and assigned it to product.

I want to filter products on frontend store using this attribute.

These attributes appear in layered navigation and working fine but I want to filter them programmatically.

I created a beforeLoad plugin for `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` using below code

```php
public function beforeLoad(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $subject, $printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
{
        if (!$subject->isLoaded()) {
            $id = 212;
            $subject->addAttributeToFilter('store_address', ['finset' => $id]);
        }

        return [$printQuery, $logQuery];
}
```

This code filter product collection based on location but toolbar and pagination data is incorrect.
For ex there are 3 product available and pagination size is 12 per page so 2 product on page 1 and 1 item appear on page 2.

I want to show all 3 items on page 1.

Please help me how can I implement this filter based on custom attribute.

Thanks

[image]